# What is __USE_MISC macro used for?

Tags: c, glibc

I am working on a project and the code contains a macro definition:

```
#define __USE_MISC
```

The code is not using it so I think it has some other purpose.

Comment: I found this in `<features.h>`

     __USE_MISC           Define things common to BSD and System V Unix

. But I still don't know what it does exactly.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

__USE_MISC is defined in `/usr/include/features.h` on the condition:

```
#if defined _BSD_SOURCE || defined _SVID_SOURCE
# define __USE_MISC     1
#endif
```

> __USE_MISC    -->       Define things common to BSD and System V Unix.

So it looks like your code wants to ensure that it's defined in any case even if both `_BSD_SOURCE` and `_SVID_SOURCE` are not defined (Since glibc 2.20, defining `_DEFAULT_SOURCE` enables `__USE_MISC`).

See [feature test macros](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Feature-Test-Macros.html) for more information.

Comment: Additionally, I'd suggest that the OP look at making sure the build environment is properly configured (and/or document the required configuration) rather than using this back-door hack.

Comment: NOTE: `_BSD_SOURCE` and `_SVID_SOURCE` has been deprecated and replaced by `_DEFAULT_SOURCE` in [glibc 2.20](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=commit;h=c941736c92fa3a319221f65f6755659b2a5e0a20) (`_DEFAULT_SOURCE` has been added in [glibc 2.19](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=commit;h=c688b4196014e0162a1ff11120f6c9516be0c6cb)).

Answer (score 6):

`__USE_MISC` is an internal detail for how the implementation's headers handle "feature test macros" that direct the compiler as to what set of standard functions should be made available to the build. As [Thiruvalluvar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10232115/12711)  indicates, it's set up (for internal use) by the library headers if your build wants a `_BSD_SOURCE` or `_SVID_SOURCE` configuration.

Your code/build should not be dealing with that macro directly; instead it should use the documented feature test macros. glibc's docs can be found here: http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Feature-Test-Macros.html

Comment: I found myself in a situation where I needed to `-ansi -D_DEFAULT_SOURCE=__STRICT_ANSI__` because `-ansi` alone left members of `struct in6_addr` undefined. `-D_DEFAULT_SOURCE=__STRICT_ANSI__` ensured `__USE_MISC` got defined. Also see [‘struct in6_addr’ has no member named ‘s6_addr32’ with -ansi](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36222072/608639). It does not feel comfortable because I have never had to do it.