# Why uint from <sys/types.h> disappears using -std=c99?

Tags: c, standards, c99

```
// Filename: test.c
#include <sys/types.h>
int main() {
    uint a;
    return 0;
}
```

The above code is able to compile using gcc and clang with standard like gnu89 or gnu99. In other words, the following works.

```
$gcc test.c # for the default is std=gnu89
$clang test.c # for the default is std=gnu99
```

However, the following fails with the error, "undeclared uint".

```
$gcc -std=c99 test.c
$clang -std=c99 test.c
```

Could some explain why the definition of uint disappears for c99 standard?

Comment: In this header file written than in case of "c99" int types are defined in inttypes.h.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The content of  is shown in [here](http://linux.die.net/include/sys/types.h), and the part related to uint is introduced as:

```
#ifdef __USE_MISC
/* Old compatibility names for C types.  */
typedef unsigned long int ulong;
typedef unsigned short int ushort;
typedef unsigned int uint;
#endif
```

This [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10231885/what-is-use-misc-macro-used-for) tells us where this peculiar macro comes from provides some basic explanation.

Careful study reveals that SVID is one standard as well, backed up by [this](http://linux.die.net/man/7/standards). The GNU standards, gnu89 and gnu99, probably cover as much stuff as possible, so the resulting behavior that uint is not included for C99 but for default standard of gcc and clang is understandable.

Answer (score 6):

Because the C standard doesn't define/require the type `uint`. It's most likely a compiler-, system- or library-specific convenience type. Don't use it.

Comment: Thanks to your hint, I have added code-level explanation for this behavior.